# FDM - Fluid Flow tutorial

Tags: differential-equations, finite-difference-method

I was reading a very nice post: http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/07/09/using-mathematica-to-simulate-and-visualize-fluid-flow-in-a-box/

But i am stuck for hours at the point where the author writes:

```
boundaries = DeleteDuplicates@
Flatten[Position[grid, #] & /@ {{0., y_}, {x_, 1.}, {1., y_}, {x_, 0.}}];
```

I can't understand the part: `Position[grid, #] &`.

Is there any other way without symbols to express that ? The closest i got is simply:

```
g = {{0., y_}, {x_, 1.}, {1., y_}, {x_, 0.}};

Map[Position[grid, #] &, g]
```

Comment: `Position[grid, #] & /@ {{0., y_}, {x_, 1.}, {1., y_}, {x_, 0.}}` is the same as `{Position[grid, {0., y_}], Position[grid, {x_, 1.}], Position[grid, {1., y_}], Position[grid, {x_, 0.}]}`.

Comment: What do you mean "without symbols"? `Position[grid, #] & /@ {{0., _}, {_, 1.}, {1., _}, {_, 0.}}` has fewer symbols, but you cannot do without `grid` (or `Position`).  Or do you want to know the names of functions for the non-letter characters?  See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616 for references.

Comment: thank you both for your answers. Michael E2 this topic really helped.